# Receiving SIGCHLD yet have spawned no child processes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I have a C program running on Linux 3.12.  This program spawns several child processes.  One of these processes spawns a thread that runs for a bit then terminates.  While this child process is running it performs an epoll_wait(). Periodically, the epoll_wait returns with an EINTR error.  I setup the child process to catch the signal doing this interruption and found it is a signal 17, which, according to everything I have read is a SIGCHLD.  Thing is, the thread this child process spawned is still running.  It did not terminate.  I also thought that threads do not generate a SIGCHLD on termination.

Any thoughts on why my process may be getting a signal 17?

Comment: 1st you want to look up (`grep` through) your implementation's headers for which signal is represented by which number, or just simply write a ssmall program that prints out all (relevant)  `SIG*` defines. Just rule out any guessing ... :-)

Comment: Checked the headers and signal 17 is defined to be SIGCHLD.

Comment: Thread or process? Provide a [mcve] with expected behaviour and how to reproduce the errorneous behaviour.

Comment: A process spawns a thread and now the process is getting SIGCHLD signals and the thread is still running.   The code is in excess of 25,000 lines so putting it here is not really practical.  That is why I was asking a more generic question.  Basically I would like to know are there other ways for a SIGCHLD to be sent other than the death of a child process.

Comment: How can you be sure there is no subprocess that died?

Comment: Not sure what would create these processes.  I do have 2 timers running that when they expire spawn a thread to go to the call back function.  But my understanding when a thread terminates it does not produce a SIGCHLD.

Comment: What do the callbacks do?

Comment: They call eventfd_write().   This is to tell the process ( that is sitting in an epoll_wait() call) that the timers expired.

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]. There are multiple assertions and conclusions in your description which may or may not be true. The only way we can verify what you are saying is if the code is shown. And we do need to verify the behaviour you are asserting before we can even begin to explain it.

Comment: Kaylum,  I understand where you are coming from and why you would like to see the code.  But, because I do not know what is causing the issue I would have to provide ALL of the code which is 10s of thousands lines of code.  That is why I am not looking for a fix to my code, what I was hoping for was an answer to this question:

What else can generate a SIGCHLD signal other than the termination of a child process?

Comment: @tpotter01 Then the general answer to your general question is that what you observe is not possible. What has happened is that the process which your thread is a part of has somehow started another process, which has terminated and given you a SIGCHLD signal (Note that you will still see this process, as a zombie process, until you call wait() on it, so make sure you don't assume the process runs just because you see it with the ps or top command). Alternatively you have a traditional bug in your code that causes you think you got a SIGCHLD - but it hasn't really happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a call to system().  This function in the code spawns a process to execute the shell command being passed in.  The thread was calling system() to run some shell commands.  When they finished the processes that was spawned ended and generated the SIGCHLD.